# Eclipse taking port 9000 even though debugging stopped

Tags: eclipse, xdebug

Eclipse was taking up port 9000. However, according to the debug view, Eclipse was not debugging.

So how do I stop Eclipse from using that port when it's not debugging, or perhaps workaround with another port? (I really don't prefer the latter.)

I'm using Windows 7, XDebug, and the Aptana plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, and SonarQube uses port 9000 which I don't want to change.

Answer (score 14):

Eclipse PHP opens port 9000 for xdebug. Change that port to something else above port 1024 in Eclipse at

Window -> Preferences -> PHP -> Debug -> Debuggers

Pick any of the entries on the left and hit 'Configure' to change the port. Restart Eclipse.

This is a problem when using Play! framework too.

Comment: I have changed the debug port to 29000, but that doesn't help, it still tries to use port 9000.

Comment: You may need to restart Eclipse.

Comment: I had restarted Eclipse, but port 9000 was still in use. Just in case it didn't like 29000, I changed the debug port to 8000 instead. So both 8000 and 9000 were in use. However, today, after a reboot and whatnot, everything seems to be in order.

Comment: I had the same problem - changing the port and restarting Eclipse did not help. Still listens on 9000 (although it also listens on the new port I specified…)

Comment: kill all java processes and start eclipse again

Comment: @Luis This doesn't work. I changed the port to 9900 and restarted my whole system. Eclipse is listening on both port 9000 and 9900.

Comment: @Dan, is there a chance you created a new configuration instead of editing the existing one? Double check your existing configurations for xdebug. Also, kill all java processes an check port 9000 in not really opened.

Comment: What do you mean by 'created a new configuration instead of editing an existing one'? Are you referring to Oomph? I don't actually have PHP or XDebug installed - I'm just using the editor. This is disabled. I'm pretty sure that it is using port 9000 because when I open the other application while Eclipse is open I get the error. I don't get an error if I close Eclipse and and start the app.

Answer (score 5):

In order to successfully free the 9000 port taken by Eclipse PDT you need to change XDebug port in:

```
Window->Preferences->PHP->Debug->Debuggers
```

if this doesn't solve the problem, also change XDebug settings in:

```
Window->Preferences->PHP->Servers
```

edit 'Default php web server', go to 'Debugger' tab, select XDebug in Debugger field and then edit port to some value other than 9000.

Comment: I confirm I had to change both (and restart Eclipse) to stop having port 9000 taken by Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem, my solution was to change XDebug server port in Eclipse not only in Debuggers and Servers sections of preferences. I found also server port in PHP Executables configuration.

When I changed all possible port settings and restart Eclipse, it stopped using 9000 port. For sure in Preferences input "debug" in search string who is upper settings menu and check all related debug settings for using 9000 port and rewrite they.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the XDebug port number at 2 different places in Eclipse:

- Preferences -> PHP -> Servers -> choose a server -> Edit -> Debugger -> Port
- Preferences -> PHP -> Debug -> Debuggers -> XDebug Configure -> Debug Port

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516305

Answer (score 0):

From my experience I am not able to stop Eclipse PDT from using port 9000. I changed port number in the XDebug settings to `9900` and now Eclipse uses port 9000 **and** 9900. In my view, this is a bug, which I've raised:

[Bug 516305 - Eclipse PDT continues using port 9000 even after changing it in XDebug settings](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516305)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change the port for me was to first changing the xdebug port in eclipse settings as explained by other posters before:

`Window->Preferences->PHP->Debug->Debuggers`

Additionally i had to *manually* edit the port in the config file `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.php.debug.core.prefs` in my eclipse workspace and change it from 9000 to something else.