# Port 9009 required by Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost is already in use

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Hi im using eclipse and tomcat to some practice of my university, the teacher give us a directory with "all that we will need" and my partners already started it. I used it on the past but recently I bougth a new pc and now when i start the tomcat v8.0 server at eclipse it doesnt work, i have this problem.

I try find some resolve it but just found some with port 80XX not with 9009, also i delete this directory and redownload it but it does nothing

Comment: Is Eclipse may be [using that port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29974892/2834978)? You should be able to check listening ports on your OS.

Comment: Just because your port number doesn't match the port number mentioned in other questions does not mean those questions are irrelevant. They are worth a closer look. Related: [Tomcat Server Error - Port 8080 already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34253779/12567365) - and various [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=tomcat+port+already+in+use+site:stackoverflow.com).

Comment: If you want to know which process is using 9009 already: [How do I find out which process is listening on a TCP or UDP port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48198/12567365) or [Check if port is open or closed on a Linux server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/309052/check-if-port-is-open-or-closed-on-a-linux-server)

Comment: (This general issue happens to me if I forget to close one running instance of Tomcat before starting a new one - especially when Tomcat is started by my IDE.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in %TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/server.xml and find 9009. Change it to another number.